# Receiving Type Error: Integer argument expected got 'str'

Tags: python, typeerror, openfiledialog

I trying to take a file and create a seperate lists of each line the file that has a combination of integers and strings, but I am getting this error, `TypeError: integer argument expected, got 'str'`. Why?

```
def main ():

    #open files allstar, playoffs, and regular season and create list by lines
        with open("C:\\Users\\wittn\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Project\\databasebasketball20_1\\player_regular_season.txt", "r") as reg_season:

            lst = list()

            for list_lines in reg_season : 

                line = reg_season.readlines(list_lines.strip())
                words = line.split (",")
            lst = [words]
        print (lst)            
main ()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Maybe you could explain what *you* think each line of your program is doing. Also, be sure to mention which line throws the exception. Your debugger, or the Python interpreter, should have told you that information, and it's key information to include in your question.

Comment: @RobKennedy right, I read the code a bit too quickly

Answer (score -1):

When reading from a file it loads it as strings use `int()` to cast it to an integer

If you don't know what values are integers and what are strings try using something like this, replacing `lst=[words]`

```
words = line.split(",")
lst = []
for word in words:
    try:
        lst.append(int(word))
    except:
        lst.append(word)
```

This algorithm attempts to convert each word to an int and if it can't just saves it as a string

Your error is occurring because when reading from a file it reads everything as a string and you need to manually convert to an int

Hope this helps

Comment: Where in the original code should *this* code go? Can you please explain why it would solve the reported error?